# Set all form field to invalid state: angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sure, i can write something like:

```
myForm.price.$setValidity('valid', true);
myForm.category.$setValidity('valid', true);
```

and

```
myForm.price.$setValidity('valid', false);
myForm.category.$setValidity('valid', false);
```

but i want to to this like function, and iterate via each field and set it to invalid state...

i tried so:

```
setValidity = function(value, form){
  _.each(form, function(field){
    if (field.$dirty === undefined || !field){
      field.$setValidity('valid', value);
    }
  });
};
```

but it doesn't work

maybe there is a good approach of doing that?

Comment: I think can just submit form to mark all field as invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using _ (underscore) which apply to array.
It should work with

```
for (fieldName in myForm) {
    myForm[fieldName].$setValidity('valid', value);
}
```